# jQuery css fixed left but absolute top

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, css-position

I've been having the hardest time getting an element to be pinned to the left side of the page but also be able to scroll up and down.

I have already tried the method where you just change the left position to $(window).scrollLeft(), but this gives a very choppy-looking animation.

What i'm looking for is the opposite of this fiddle, but I can't quite get it to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/F7Bme/

```
var leftInit = $(".scroll_fixed").offset().left;
var top = $('.scroll_fixed').offset().top - parseFloat($('.scroll_fixed').css('margin-       top').replace(/auto/, 0));

$(window).scroll(function(event) {
   var x = 0 - $(this).scrollLeft();
   var y = $(this).scrollTop();

// whether that's below the form
if (y >= top) {
    // if so, ad the fixed class
    $('.scroll_fixed').addClass('fixed');
} else {
    // otherwise remove it
    $('.scroll_fixed').removeClass('fixed');
}

$(".scroll_fixed").offset({
    left: x + leftInit
   });
});
```

Notice that this div is fixed top but not left. I'm looking for the opposite, fixed left and not top. Any ideas?

I tried editing this fiddle but can't get it working.

Comment: what is expected to happen if the window is scrolled half way horizontally and then scrolled vertically without returning to horizontal scroll to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This woks:

```
var leftInit = $(".scroll_fixed").offset().left;
var top = $('.scroll_fixed').offset().top - parseFloat($('.scroll_fixed').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));

$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  var x = $(this).scrollLeft();
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();

  // whether that's below the form
  if (x >= leftInit) {
      // if so, ad the fixed class
      $('.scroll_fixed').addClass('fixed');
  } else {
      // otherwise remove it
      $('.scroll_fixed').removeClass('fixed');
  }

  $(".scroll_fixed").offset({
      left: x + leftInit
  });
});
```

**EDIT** Also change

```
.scroll_fixed.fixed {
  position:absolute;
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me...it is pinned left but also top, I ONLY want it pinned left and NOT top.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you wanted http://jsfiddle.net/F7Bme/958/

```
.scroll_fixed {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 0;
}
.scroll_fixed div {
    float: left;
    position: relative
}
```

And forgot about JS

Comment: This may be a simplified example.  the JS may be necessary for part of the functionality that the OP decided was not relevant to the question, but good answer.